# Extending a partial order to antichains

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, terminology, order-theory

Let $(S, \leq)$ be a partial order. Let $T$ be the set of antichains of $S$ (i.e., subsets of $S$ whose elements are pairwise incomparable). Define a relation $\leq'$ on $T$ as follows: for all $A$, $B \in T$, $A \leq' B$ iff $\forall x \in A, \exists y \in B, x \leq y$.

It seems to me that $\leq'$ is also a partial order (it is reflexive, transitive and antisymmetric), and I feel this construction is natural enough to be standard, but I can't find a name for it. How is this construction called? Are there other ways to extend a partial order on a set to a partial order on antichains?

Bonus question: Does $\leq'$ share some of $\leq$'s properties? For instance, if $\leq$ is a well-quasi-ordering, is $\leq'$ also a well-quasi-ordering?

Comment: This ordering (and one closely related) is known. See my post about [game trees](http://wimcouwenberg.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/game-trees-under-a-partial-order-part-1/) and look for the definition of minimizing and maximizing order.  I also encountered these orderings elsewhere but I'll have to search for a reference.  Not sure if there's a name for them.

Comment: See [here](http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/research/techreps/2000/bbkcs-00-09.pdf) for example.

Comment: @Wim: This is thoroughly off-topic, but that is a wonderfully appropriate picture on your Math Blog!

Comment: WimC: A more detailed paper about the same thing by the same authors: http://isg.rhul.ac.uk/~jason/Pubs/imj.pdf

Comment: Just wanted to comment that, in the particular case where $B \subseteq A$, the relation defined in the first paragraph is called "$B$ is cofinal in $A$": see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofinal_(mathematics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For finite posets at least, there is a one to one correspondence between antichains and lower sets (an antichain $A$ defines the lower sets of elements $x$ such that $\exists y \in A,\,x \leq y$, and conversely the set of maximal elements of a lower set is an antichain). The order relation I have just given is the image of the inclusion order on lower sets under this correspondence: $A \leq' B$ iff $\overline{A} \subseteq \overline{B}$ for $\overline{A}$ and $\overline{B}$ the lower sets associated to $A$ and $B$.

The order induced by the inclusion order of the lower sets of a poset is well-known: is is a [distributive lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice), and [Birkhoff's representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff%27s_representation_theorem) states that the mapping from posets to the distributive lattice of the inclusion order on its lower set is one-to-one. To wrap it up, the order relation I described in my question is isomorphic to the distributive lattice associated to $(S, \leq)$ by Birkhoff's representation theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Anent the bonus question: if $(P,\le)$ is well-quasi-ordered, then $(T,\le')$ is well-quasi-ordered, where $T$ is the set of all antichains of $P$.

**Proof.** Assume for a contradiction that $T$ is not well-quasi-ordered; *i.e.*, there is an infinite sequence $A_1,A_2,A_3,\dots$ in $T$ such that $A_i\not\le'A_j$ whenever $i\lt j$. Since $P$ is well-quasi-ordered, the antichains $A_i$ are finite.

For each $j\gt1$ there is some $x\in A_1$ such that $\{x\}\not\le'A_j$. Since $A_1$ is finite, there exist an element $a_1\in A_1$ and an infinite set $N_1\subseteq\{2,3,\cdots\}$ such that $\{a_1\}\not\le'A_j$ for all $j\in N_1$.

Next, let $i_2=\min N_1$; there exist $a_2\in A_{i_2}$ and an infinite set $N_2\subseteq N_1\setminus\{a_2\}$ such that $a_2\not\le'A_j$ for all $j\in N_2$.

Continuing in this way, we get an infinite sequence $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots\}$ in $P$ such that $a_i\not\le a_j$ whenever $i\lt j$; but this contradicts our assumption that $P$ is well-quasi-ordered.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! I guess that this is a variant of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higman%27s_lemma

Comment: I guess it must be a corollary of Higman's or some other standard result from wqo theory, but I was too lazy to look into the matter.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true, in general, that there is a 1-to-1 correspondence between antichains and lower sets. It is true if the poset satisfies the ascending chain condition.

Here's a counterexample. Take as the poset the unit interval with the usual order: $([0,1], \leq)$. Consider the set $S = [0, 1)$. Then $S$ is a lower set, because for any $x\in S$, any $y\leq x$ is in S. However, $S$ has no maximal elements.

Comment: Thanks for this remark! In my answer I was implicitly thinking about *finite* posets, even though the question was more general. I rephrased accordingly.